# How do I fix this Flutter dependencies error

Tags: ios, flutter

I’m running into an error, when I try to build my flutter app using xcode, I’m trying to upgrade the ios version from 8 to 12, but I’m getting “the dependencies are outdated error” how do I fix this. I’m really new to flutter. Thanks in advance

tried running it using version 12 ios

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter you can upgrade packages with the command:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

If the problem persists, it is because during the last compilation of your code there was some cache left with old data. So the best thing you can do is:

```
flutter clean
```

(which removes temporary files that are generated to speed up subsequent compilations.)

so now recompile your code and everything will work :)

**Note:**
if your code is a bit old and uses old packages. it might not be a good idea to update packages since it assumes that "this app works with this version" by updating packages things might break. So make a backup of the code and version of the packages first (you can find it in pubspec.yaml)

Or you can try downloading an older version of Flutter and try compiling.

The only solution then is to Experiment!

Enjoy :)

Comment: @speednation If it worked remember to mark this question as valid to help other people in your condition :)